# Error creating bean with name 'eurekaInstanceConfigBean': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

This question is extension of [Working With Eureka Clients Programmatically issue - Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955613/working-with-eureka-clients-programmatically-issue-completed-shut-down-of-disc). On my windows machine `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` both versions where different. I just corrected it and now its showing me below error.

Error:

> Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaInstanceConfigBean': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)

I already went through the urls like :[Error creating bean with name and Singleton bean creation not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017746/error-creating-bean-with-name-and-singleton-bean-creation-not-allowed) and https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1064, but these suggestions are not clear.

The complete error trace:

```
2018-12-28 19:44:02.188  INFO 22184 --- [       Thread-6] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@dc9876b: startup date [Fri Dec 28 19:43:59 IST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6e20b53a
2018-12-28 19:44:02.188  INFO 22184 --- [       Thread-6] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Unregistering application MYCLIENT with eureka with status DOWN
2018-12-28 19:44:02.188  WARN 22184 --- [       Thread-6] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1546006442188, current=DOWN, previous=UP]
2018-12-28 19:44:02.188  INFO 22184 --- [       Thread-6] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2018-12-28 19:44:02.190  INFO 22184 --- [       Thread-6] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-12-28 19:44:02.190  INFO 22184 --- [       Thread-6] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-12-28 19:44:02.192  INFO 22184 --- [       Thread-6] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2018-12-28 19:44:02.194  WARN 22184 --- [       Thread-6] .s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaInstanceConfigBean': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add the **web** dependency. I am not clear why with the addition of **web** dependencies works/solves this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding the web dependency" ? Put at least an explicit reference to the above mentioned SO : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983987/6466510