# Spring Boot Microservices are shutting down with : Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am using following pom.xml for my eureka server. I have couple of micro services which are registered with eureka server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.etp</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eureka-server</name>
    <description>Spring Boot eureka-server</description>

    <properties>
        <!-- <java.version>1.8</java.version> -->
        <!--Build-Date -->
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>dd-MMM-yyyy</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <!--Build-Date -->
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

All services gets registered approximately and then they automatically shuts down themselves either with docker status code 0 or 137. I tried to check logs for both and found following stack for both status code services

```
log="24-09-2021 09:45:33.965 [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register - DiscoveryClient_MYMICROSERVICE/mymicroservice:56e852b73630a712fbdf9defedaa6cef: registering service..."
log="24-09-2021 09:45:33.910 [SpringContextShutdownHook] ERROR com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.notify - Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1632476733910, current=DOWN, previous=UP]"
log="24-09-2021 09:45:33.889 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.deregister - Unregistering application MYMICROSERVICE with eureka with status DOWN"
log="24-09-2021 09:45:34.598 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.shutdown - Shutting down DiscoveryClient ..."
container_name=/mymicroservice source=stdout log="24-09-2021 09:45:34.524 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.shutdown - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'" container_id=5b50472ae3437072dfe79c664a71dc305513d928b7173839c904dfe1abd7081e
container_name=/mymicroservice source=stdout log="24-09-2021 09:45:34.034 [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register - DiscoveryClient_MYMICROSERVICE/mymicroservice:56e852b73630a712fbdf9defedaa6cef - registration status: 204" container_id=5b50472ae3437072dfe79c664a71dc305513d928b7173839c904dfe1abd7081e
log="24-09-2021 09:45:37.629 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.unregister - Unregistering ..."
log="24-09-2021 09:45:42.755 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.unregister -DiscoveryClient_MYMICROSERVICE/mymicroservice:56e852b73630a712fbdf9defedaa6cef - deregister status: 200"
log="24-09-2021 09:45:43.030 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.shutdown - Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient"
```

With log level TRACE I am getting following logs ,

```
28-09-2021 11:03:38.828  org.apache.http.wire.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
28-09-2021 11:03:38.828  org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 404
28-09-2021 11:03:38.828  org.apache.http.headers.receiveResponseHeader - << HTTP/1.1 404
28-09-2021 11:03:38.829  org.apache.http.headers.receiveResponseHeader - << Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
28-09-2021 11:03:38.829  org.apache.http.headers.receiveResponseHeader - << Date: Tue, 28 Sep 2021 11:03:38 GMT
28-09-2021 11:03:38.829  org.apache.http.headers.receiveResponseHeader - << Content-Type: application/xml
28-09-2021 11:03:38.829  org.apache.http.headers.receiveResponseHeader - << Content-Length: 0
28-09-2021 11:03:38.829  org.apache.http.headers.receiveResponseHeader - << Connection: keep-alive
28-09-2021 11:03:38.829  org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
28-09-2021 11:03:38.829  com.netflix.discovery.shared.MonitoredConnectionManager.releaseConnection - Released connection is reusable.
28-09-2021 11:03:38.830  com.netflix.discovery.shared.NamedConnectionPool.freeEntry - Releasing connection [{s}->https://dev-eureka.myapp.com:443][null]
28-09-2021 11:03:38.830  com.netflix.discovery.shared.NamedConnectionPool.freeEntry - Pooling connection [{s}->https://dev-eureka.myapp.com:443][null]; keep alive indefinitely
28-09-2021 11:03:38.830  com.netflix.discovery.shared.NamedConnectionPool.notifyWaitingThread - Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
28-09-2021 11:03:38.830  com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.cancel - Jersey HTTP DELETE https://dev-eureka.myapp.com/eureka//apps/my-microservice/MY-APP:50c9e928d934dbdeb4abfecc1a8b9ef1; statusCode=404
28-09-2021 11:03:38.830  [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.unregister - DiscoveryClient_my-microservice/MY-APP:50c9e928d934dbdeb4abfecc1a8b9ef1 - deregister  status: 404
28-09-2021 11:03:39.030  com.netflix.discovery.shared.MonitoredConnectionManager.closeIdleConnections - Closing connections idle longer than 0 SECONDS
28-09-2021 11:03:39.055  com.netflix.discovery.shared.NamedConnectionPool.closeIdleConnections - Closing connections idle longer than 0 SECONDS
28-09-2021 11:03:39.056  com.netflix.discovery.shared.NamedConnectionPool.closeIdleConnections - Closing connection last used @ Tue Sep 28 11:03:38 GMT 2021
28-09-2021 11:03:39.056  com.netflix.discovery.shared.NamedConnectionPool.deleteEntry - Deleting connection [{s}->https://dev-eureka.myapp.com:443][null]
28-09-2021 11:03:39.056  org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.close - Connection 0.0.0.0:59650<->IP:443 closed
28-09-2021 11:03:39.080  com.netflix.discovery.shared.MonitoredConnectionManager.shutdown - Shutting down
28-09-2021 11:03:39.228  [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.shutdown - Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient
28-09-2021 11:03:39.228  [SpringContextShutdownHook] TRACE org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroyBean - Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory': [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor]
```

Update 1: main class

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
@FeignClient(name = "myapp")
@RibbonClient(name = "myapp")
public class CreateUserServiceApplication {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getFormatterLogger();

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        /* returning object of RestTemplate */
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* APPLICATION START-UP */
        String logID = RandomNumberGenerator.generateRandomNumberForLOG();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        /* declaring objects */
        SpringApplication application = null;
        ApplicationContext appCnt = null;
        try {
            /* ============= BUSINESS LOGIC ================= */
            System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");

            /* defining application class */
            application = new SpringApplication(CreateUserServiceApplication.class);

            /*-----RUN APPLICATION-------------*/
            appCnt = SpringApplication.run(CreateUserServiceApplication.class, args);
            //setHibernateConfig(logID);

            /* setting properties into application */
            Map<String, Object> appProperties = setApplicationConstant(appCnt);
            Configuration.setPropertyValue(appProperties);
            application.setDefaultProperties(appProperties);
            createSessionOfDatabase(logID);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ExceptionLogger.logException(e, logID);
        }
        /* timer variable */
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }   
}
```

bootstrap.yaml

```
server:
  port:8080
             
eureka:
  instance:
      instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${random.value}
      ##instanceId: controller:${random.value}
      ## this should not be enabled on production
      leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
      leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
      ##hostname: ${host.name} 
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${server.ip}
      eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled: true
      lease:duration: 1
      
      
spring.cloud.config.uri: http://IP:PORT
      
spring.application.name: SERVICE_NAME
   

host:
  name: ${createUser.host.name}

logging:
  config: configuration/logback.xml

management:
   endpoint:
      refresh:
       enabled: true
```

I have referred [link1](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2696) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955613/working-with-eureka-clients-programmatically-issue-completed-shut-down-of-disc) but none of them resolved the issue. Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Have you tried with TRACE debugging? Usually there are a lot more things going on that Spring does not show you by default

Comment: I have updated my question with the TRACE logs as you suggested. Please have a look.

Comment: Can you post your code: at least the class with annotation `@SpringBootApplication` and the application.yml (or properties).

Comment: @рüффп I have added main class and bootstrap.yaml. Please have a look.